# union of finite dimensional subspaces is dense?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let X be a real reflexiv Banachspace (with possible uncountable dimension),
In the lecture it was used that the union of all finite dimensional subspaces of X is dense i.e

$$
\overline{\cup_{Y=\text{f. dim.}} Y}=X
$$

Is this statement in generell true? if yes, has anyone a proof?

Answer (score 4):

For each $x\in X$, take $Y_x=\mathbb C x$. Then each $Y_x$ is one-dimensional, and
$$
X=\bigcup_{x\in X}Y_x,
$$
no need for any closure.